# I want to create triangle using CSS and want to fill color inside it using inset How to do that??? Please Answer

Tags: javascript, html, css

**I want to create triangle using CSS and want to fill color inside it using inset How to do that??? Please Answer....**

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

}

body{
    background: linear-gradient(15deg, #00ffff, #004680);
    background-position: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}

.bubble{
    position: absolute;
    top: 40vh;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    
    border-radius: 50%;     
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #fff, inset -10px 10px 15px #020131,
    inset 5px 5px 10px #960101, inset -5px 5px 20px #fff,
    inset 15px -25px 20px #9224ed;
}
//I want to create triangle using CSS and want to fill color inside it using inset How to do //that??? Please Answer....
.bubble-two{
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #fff, inset -10px 10px 15px #06f3df,
    inset 5px 5px 10px #f8e63e, inset -5px 5px 20px #fff,
    inset 15px -25px 20px #ed24aa;

}

.bubble-three {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #010631, inset -10px 10px 15px #1512f3,
    inset 5px 5px 10px #f8e63e, inset -5px 5px 20px #fff,
    inset 15px -25px 20px #33114e;

}

.bubble-four{
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #8b0101, inset -10px 10px 15px #f6f6fc,
    inset 5px 5px 10px #81f733, inset -5px 5px 20px #fff,
    inset 15px -25px 20px #0b0822;

}

.bubble-five{
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #fff, inset -10px 10px 15px #100dee,
    inset 5px 5px 10px #f7a120, inset -5px 5px 20px #fff,
    inset 15px -25px 20px #ed24c1;

}

.score-board{
    background: #fff;
    width: 300px;
    height: 80px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 20px 20px 0 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left:calc(50% - 150px) ;
}

.loser {
    display: none;

}
.winner {
    display: none;
    
}

.main-game{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

button.start-btn{
    font-size: 20px;
    border: none;
    margin-top: 8px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 30px;
    width: 5%;
    margin: 8px auto;
    
}

.shadow{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    display: none;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 1000;
    position: relative;
}

.total-score{
    background: #fff;
    padding: 10px 100px 40px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<div class="bubble bubble-one"></div>
```

**I want to create triangle using CSS and want to fill color inside it using inset How to do that??? Please Answer....**

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? And what should we do? Not sure I got it, you should write it a fifth time. What about a good old [triangle generator](https://www.google.com/search?q=css+triangle+generator)?

Comment: Are you saying you want to create a triangle instead of the circle? What have you tried?

Comment: On running the code snippet you will see a circle with some colors on it's inside. This is done by setting border-radius to 50% and adding box-shadow with inset. I would like to have the similar color combination but now the shape being a triangle.

Comment: @AHaworth Please Answer How to do that ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The circle is formed by using border-radius of 50%.

If you remove that and instead put in a clip-path which has value of a polygon with 3 coordinates then you get a triangle, as in this snippet.

Obviously you will want to experiment with how the colors are placed and also what angle and size/ratios you want to apply to the various triangles.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(15deg, #00ffff, #004680);
  background-position: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.bubble {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40vh;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /*border-radius: 50%;   */
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #fff, inset -10px 10px 15px #020131, inset 5px 5px 10px #960101, inset -5px 5px 20px #fff, inset 15px -25px 20px #9224ed;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}

.bubble-two {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #fff, inset -10px 10px 15px #06f3df, inset 5px 5px 10px #f8e63e, inset -5px 5px 20px #fff, inset 15px -25px 20px #ed24aa;
}

.bubble-three {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #010631, inset -10px 10px 15px #1512f3, inset 5px 5px 10px #f8e63e, inset -5px 5px 20px #fff, inset 15px -25px 20px #33114e;
}

.bubble-four {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #8b0101, inset -10px 10px 15px #f6f6fc, inset 5px 5px 10px #81f733, inset -5px 5px 20px #fff, inset 15px -25px 20px #0b0822;
}

.bubble-five {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #fff, inset -10px 10px 15px #100dee, inset 5px 5px 10px #f7a120, inset -5px 5px 20px #fff, inset 15px -25px 20px #ed24c1;
}

.score-board {
  background: #fff;
  width: 300px;
  height: 80px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 20px 20px 0 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: calc(50% - 150px);
}

.loser {
  display: none;
}

.winner {
  display: none;
}

.main-game {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

button.start-btn {
  font-size: 20px;
  border: none;
  margin-top: 8px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 30px;
  width: 5%;
  margin: 8px auto;
}

.shadow {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  display: none;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 1000;
  position: relative;
}

.total-score {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 10px 100px 40px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<div class="bubble bubble-one"></div>
```